# How must I change my code to make more than one line shape?

Tags: wpf

I want to draw lines in a "touch" application in WPF and wrote the following code:

**XAML (part)**:

```
<Canvas x:Name="MainCanvas"
            IsManipulationEnabled="True"
            TouchDown="MainCanvas_TouchDown" 
            TouchUp="MainCanvas_TouchUp">
```

**C#**:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Line myLine = new Line();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void MainCanvas_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        myLine.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightSteelBlue;
        myLine.StrokeThickness = 2;
        // Line's starting point
        myLine.X1 = e.GetTouchPoint(this).Position.X;
        myLine.Y1 = e.GetTouchPoint(this).Position.Y;
    }

    public void MainCanvas_TouchUp(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        // Line's ending point
        myLine.X2 = e.GetTouchPoint(this).Position.X;
        myLine.Y2 = e.GetTouchPoint(this).Position.Y;

        MainCanvas.Children.Add(myLine);


    }
}
```

With this, I'm able to draw only one line. If I try to draw another, the application crashes.

Comment: When you say "it crashes" what is the error?

Comment: A message box shows, saying "MyApp stopped working", with two buttons : "Debug" and "Close program". I think it's normal here, because I'm always working with the same variable (and the second time, it tries to add it to MainCanvas, but as it's already added, the app crashes).

Comment: @brasofilo : thank you, I did has you said. Thanks also for editing my question, I studied the changes you made so I'll write my future questions better :)

Comment: Really glad to hear :) I don't know much of the subject, but maybe a more descriptive title would be: `How to make more than one line shape in WPF?`. . . I think the recipe to good answers and upvotes is: descriptive title, well researched and formatted content, and sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each line that you want to draw, you will have to create a new `Line` instance. In your current code, you have just one `Line` instance, but that instance represents exactly one displayed line.

Unlike other graphics toolkits where you use various objects to draw graphical elements onto a drawing surface step by step, WPF works like vector graphics: Each of the objects you use *is* a graphical element; for two identical graphical elements, you will need two objects with the same properties.

Therefore, when you add the same graphical object for the second time, in this line:

```
MainCanvas.Children.Add(myLine);
```

An exception will be thrown, because you can only add each graphical element once.

As you want to add an arbitrary number of lines, store your lines in a list and add a new line instance (i.e. instantiate the `Line` class and add your new line to the canvas) in the touch-down event. In the touch-up event, set the second point of the new instance (the last element in your list).

*Please be aware that this is not about C#, it is about WPF. (In other words, a C# pro who has never worked with WPF will not be able to tell you, but a WPF developer who has never used C# (always VB.NET, for example) might help.*

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH ! With your explanation, everything went finally clear to me. I'm updating my first message with the solution. 

Thanks also for the precision about WPF/C#. I'm removing the C# tag and C# in the title (if possible).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to O. R. Mapper's answer, here's the solution. As he explains, for each line a new Line instance must be created.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<Line> lines = new List<Line>();

    public void MainCanvas_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        Line myLine = new Line();           
        myLine.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightSteelBlue;
        myLine.StrokeThickness = 2;
        myLine.X1 = e.GetTouchPoint(this).Position.X;
        myLine.Y1 = e.GetTouchPoint(this).Position.Y;
        lines.Add(myLine);
    }

    public void MainCanvas_TouchUp(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        lines[lines.Count - 1].X2 = e.GetTouchPoint(this).Position.X;
        lines[lines.Count - 1].Y2 = e.GetTouchPoint(this).Position.Y;
        MainCanvas.Children.Add(lines[lines.Count - 1]);
    }
}
```